# Подскажите счетчик

Tags: javascript, jquery

Поступила задачка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно при скролле ленда запустить от 1 до определенного числа счетчик.

Сложных условий не нужно, просто чтоб цифры прошли цикл от 1 и да 40 например.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так, например:

```js
function runCounter(el, min, max, time) {
  var i = min;
  var wait = 21, range = max - min, step = range * wait / time;
  var ivl = setInterval(function() {
    i += step;
    el.text(Math.round(i));
    if(i >= max) {
      el.text(max);
      clearInterval(ivl);
    }
  }, wait);
}

runCounter($("#dov_klient"), 0, 1600, 3000);
runCounter($("#zam_koles"), 0, 3200, 3000);
runCounter($("#raz_blyud"), 0, 40, 3000);
runCounter($("#chashek_kofe"), 0, 20000, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Довольных клиентов</td>
    <td>Заменянных колес</td>
    <td>Разных блюд</td>
    <td>Выпитых чашек кофе</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="dov_klient"></td>
    <td id="zam_koles"></td>
    <td id="raz_blyud"></td>
    <td id="chashek_kofe"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
(function myFunc ()
{
if (self.TMR) clearTimeout (TMR);
var obj = document.getElementById ('cnt');
obj.innerHTML = parseInt (obj.innerHTML) + 1;
TMR = setTimeout (myFunc, Math.random () * 2345);
}) ();
</script>
<span id="cnt">0</span>
```

Comment: в моём случае до бесконечности будет считать от 0 пока страницу не закроют.